# Choosing the first child record in a selfjoin in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, join, subquery

I've got a `visits` table that looks like this:

```
id identity(1,1) not null,
visit_date datetime not null,
patient_id int not null,
flag bit not null
```

For each record, I need to find a matching record that is same time or earlier, has the same patient_id, and has `flag` set to 1. What I am doing now is:

```
select parent.id as parent_id, 
(
   select top 1 
      child.id as child_id
   from 
      visits as child
   where 
     child.visit_date <= parent.visit_date
     and child.patient_id = parent.patient_id
     and child.flag = 1
   order by 
     visit_date desc
 ) as child_id
from 
   visits as parent
```

So, this query works correctly, except that it runs too slow -- I suspect that this is because of the subquery. Is it possible to rewrite it as a joined query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   /* 
    id identity(1,1) not null,
    visit_date datetime not null,
    patient_id int not null,
    flag bit not null
   */

SELECT
    T.parentId,
    T.patientId,
    V.id AS childId
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        visit.id AS parentId,
        visit.patient_id AS patientId,
        MAX (previous_visit.visit_date) previousVisitDate
    FROM
        visit
        LEFT JOIN visit previousVisit ON
            visit.patient_id = previousVisit.patient_id
            AND visit.visit_date >= previousVisit.visit_date
            AND visit.id <> previousVisit.id
            AND previousVisit.flag = 1
    GROUP BY
        visit.id,
        visit.visit_date,
        visit.patient_id,
        visit.flag
    ) AS T
    LEFT JOIN visit V ON
      T.patientId = V.patient_id
      AND T.previousVisitDate = V.visit_date
```

Answer (score 1):

View the query execution plan. Where you have thick arrows, look at those statements. You should learn the different statements and what they imply, like what Clustered Index Scan/ Seek etc.

Usually when a query is going slow however I find that there are no good indexes.

The tables and columns affected and used to join, create an index that covers all these columns. This is called a covering index usually in the forums. It's something you can do for something that really needs it. But keep in mind that too many indexes will slow down insert statements.